# How to use XmlHolder.removeDomNodes() with namespaces in SOAP-UI

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, soapui

I have a namespace-aware xml structure and want to remove one node in XmlHolder. Whenever I specify the name space (by un-commenting one of the two lines below) I receive the following exception at the line of `removeDomNodes`:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath
>   syntax error at char 1 on line 2 in {\ndeclare namespace ns}:
>   Unexpected token "declare namespace" in path expression error

**Example:**

```java
def soapmessage = '''<ns:basket xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
                    |   <ns:fruit>
                    |      <ns:name>banana</ns:name>
                    |      <ns:color>yellow</ns:color>
                    |     </ns:fruit>
                    |   <ns:fruit>
                    |      <ns:name>apple</ns:name>
                    |      <ns:color>green</ns:color>
                    |     </ns:fruit>
                    |   <ns:fruit>
                    |      <ns:name>strawberry</ns:name>
                    |      <ns:color>red</ns:color>
                    |     </ns:fruit>
                    |</ns:basket>'''.stripMargin()


def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )

def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( soapmessage )
  //holder.namespaces["ns"] = "http://example.com"
  //holder.declareNamespace("ns", "http://example.com")

assert holder.getNodeValue("//ns:fruit[2]/ns:color[1]") == "green"

holder.removeDomNodes("//ns:fruit[2]")

assert holder.getNodeValue("//ns:fruit[2]/ns:color[1]") == "red"
```

**Question:**
It would work if I just let the namespace-declaration commented. But I need them for other methods to work. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For removing your node, there is no value in specifying the namespace:

```
holder.removeDomNodes('//*:fruit[2]')
```

Alternatively, you could try something like:

```
holder.getDomNode('//*:basket').removeChild('/*:fruit[2]')
```